# How to parse tags within search by tag name?

Tags: html, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to get all href address from http://star.sse.com.cn/renewal.
I found that all hrefs are included in this tag:`<div class="chart-9">`, so I tried to search by class name.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://star.sse.com.cn/renewal')
issuerSearch = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('chart-9')
issuer = list(filter(None, [i.text for i in issuerSearch]))

for a in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('chart-9 a'):
     print(a.get_attribute('href'))
driver.close()
```

But the above does not seem to work. The `a.get_attribute('href')`gives an empty list.
Then I tried to use regex:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://star.sse.com.cn/renewal')
data = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.innerHTML;")
classSearch = re.findall('<div class="chart-9.{1,200}', data)
```

Here I met another problem: `data` does not give the whole content of web elements.
It's like this: `<table class="table search_zcz_dt_info"></table></div>`.
The table body gets truncated completely.
Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

try to get all of the elements first:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://star.sse.com.cn/renewal')
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@href]')
```

then parse each element getting href attribute:

```
urls = [el.get_attribute('href') for el in elements]
print(urls)
```

code should looks like that:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://star.sse.com.cn/renewal')
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@href]')

urls = [el.get_attribute('href') for el in elements]
print(urls)

driver.quit()
```

you can all check if url valid and there're only address with 'http' like:

```
urls = [el.get_attribute('href') for el in elements if 'http' in el.get_attribute('href')]
```

Comment: Somehow this only gives hrefs from <div class="header"> and <div class="footer">, and ignores content in <main class="main">. All my desired hrefs are in main tag.

Comment: @Zzzqn good, you have you tried `elements = driver.find_elelents_by_xpath('//main[@href]')`? where main - is your required tag

Answer (score 1):

```
Hrefs = [ x.get_attribute("href") for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='chart-9']//a[@href]")]
print(Hrefs)
```

To get all a tags href values in the div class chart9 you do the following.

Page load seems to be an issue use the below instead

```
Hrefs = [x.get_attribute("href") for x in WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='chart-9']//a[@href]")))]
```

Imports

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Outputs:

```
['http://kcb.sse.com.cn/renewal/xmxq/index.shtml?auditId=333&anchor_type=0', 'http://kcb.sse.com.cn/renewal/xmxq/index.shtml?auditId=711&anchor_type=0', 'http://kcb.sse.com.cn/renewal/xmxq/index.shtml?auditId=856&anchor_type=0', 'http://kcb.sse.com.cn/renewal/xmxq/index.shtml?auditId=536&anchor_type=0', 'http://kcb.sse.com.cn/renewal/xmxq/index.shtml?auditId=687&anchor_type=0', 'http://kcb.sse.com.cn/renewal/xmxq/index.shtml?auditId=644&anchor_type=0', 'http://kcb.sse.com.cn/renewal/xmxq/index.shtml?auditId=746&anchor_type=0', 'http://kcb.sse.com.cn/renewal/xmxq/index.shtml?auditId=642&anchor_type=0', 'http://kcb.sse.com.cn/renewal/xmxq/index.shtml?auditId=573&anchor_type=0', 'http://kcb.sse.com.cn/renewal/xmxq/index.shtml?auditId=631&anchor_type=0', 'http://kcb.sse.com.cn/renewal/xmxq/index.shtml?auditId=543&anchor_type=0', 'http://kcb.sse.com.cn/renewal/xmxq/index.shtml?auditId=851&anchor_type=0', 'http://kcb.sse.com.cn/renewal/xmxq/index.shtml?auditId=580&anchor_type=0', 'http://kcb.sse.com.cn/renewal/xmxq/index.shtml?auditId=708&anchor_type=0', 'http://kcb.sse.com.cn/renewal/xmxq/index.shtml?auditId=597&anchor_type=0', 'http://kcb.sse.com.cn/renewal/xmxq/index.shtml?auditId=709&anchor_type=0', 'http://kcb.sse.com.cn/renewal/xmxq/index.shtml?auditId=764&anchor_type=0', 'http://kcb.sse.com.cn/renewal/xmxq/index.shtml?auditId=794&anchor_type=0', 'http://kcb.sse.com.cn/renewal/xmxq/index.shtml?auditId=761&anchor_type=0', 'http://kcb.sse.com.cn/renewal/xmxq/index.shtml?auditId=786&anchor_type=0']
```

Comment: I changed your 'chart9' to 'chart-9' and the code still does not work somehow. Hrefs is an empty list. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried it with chart-9 and it gives all the hrefs like so. Maybe the page load is causing problems.

Comment: I just learned that the table needs a WebDriverWait condition to load. Now I succeeded. Thank you!

Comment: No problem have a nice day.